# Ф.И.О. в подписи и в самом письме

Tags: орфография, этикет

В электронных письмах, в этом конкретном случае – gmail, в подписи у меня указан следующий текст:

```
С уважением,
Иванов Иван.

Тел.: +111 111-11-1111 и т. д.
```

Проблема в том, что подпись не видна постоянно (пока этот блок не открыть, он не покажется).

Не очень ли "грубо" не писать своё имя или можно дублировать Ф.И.О. в конце письма? Будет ли это корректно? Или же будет правильнее убрать "С уважением, Иванов Иван" из подписи? Как вообще правильно или принято это делать?

Так сейчас выглядит письмо:

```
Здравствуйте, Пётр.

[тело письма]

Иван.
--------------------
С уважением,
Иванов Иван.

Тел.: +111 111-11-1111 и т. д.
```

Благодарю.

## Изменение 1:

Заранее прошу прощения, за чёрные квадраты вместо текстов и названий.

Так выглядит письмо в gmail, с закрытым контейнером:
[image: закрытый контейнер]

Так выглядит уже открытый контейнер того же письма:
[image: после открытия контейнера]
Как тут видно, сначала идёт история переписки, и только затем идёт подпись.
Если переписка большая, то до самой подписи добираться не удобно. Тем самым, никто и не увидит надпись `С уважением, ..`.

Comment: После подписи точку не ставят.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой суть ведь не в этом

Comment: Не в этом, конечно, но это тоже полезно узнать заодно. ;)

Comment: *Проблема в том, что подпись не видна постоянно (пока этот блок не открыть, он не покажется).* - как сие понимать? Вы полагаете, что получатель не видит вашу подпись?

Comment: Да, @behemothus, нажав на кнопку "..." в конце письма подпись появляется, по умолчанию подпись спрятана. Также, в спрятанном контейнере ещё хранится история переписок, соответственно нужная надпись идёт в самый низ и если история переписок большая, то вероятность что кто-то спуститься до конца ещё меньше.

Comment: @DalerAzimov У меня ничего подобного не происходит. Отправлял и читал с gmail на mail.ru и наоборот. Подписи везде отображаются корректно.  Никаких вредных контейнеров.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Если адресат априори подозревается в том, что он до подписи письмо всё равно не дочитает, то суть не в точке, это да...

Comment: @behemothus, посмотрите, пожалуйста изменение 1. Продемонстрировал, как это выглядит в gmail. Благодарю!

Comment: Как это выглядит в gmail - см. в моем ответе. А все остальное выясняйте в настройках. В любом случае прежде, чем что-то обманівать интерфейс поинтересуйтесь у своих корреспондентов, как **они** это видят в своей почтовой среде.

Answer (score 0):

Не поленился, отправил себе пару писем с ответами...
Вот вам картинка, ***как это выглядит на самом деле*** - и идите разбираться в настройки. Или в гугл.
Это тема не для русского языка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]